# SMA390 RPC port not responding for public facing IP

Tags: security, cisco, cisco-ios

I have been working on CISCO's SMA390 and the RPC port for the device is not responsive when connected to a core switch.
1. The core switch is for public-facing IP/ CIMC IP of the device.
2. The IP's are configured and using ipmitool command.
3. The port is responding when tried to configure over a private network(laptop to device connection).

I have tried ping command after checking that the IP's are configured and its failing while the gateway is responding.

ipmitool lan print 1
ipmitool lan set 1 ipsrc static
ipmitool lan set 1 ipaddr 10.10.1.5
ipmitool lan set 1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ipmitool lan set 1 defgw ipaddr 10.10.1.1
ipmitool lan set 1 access on
ipmitool raw 0x36 0x52 0x0f

I want the ping and the ssh to be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out after some more troubleshooting that CISCO x90 devices by default work on 100G bandwidth connection. The default provided on x95 devices is 1000G bandwidth connection. Hence the RPC port didn't respond.

If you face this issue, try 
1. using a 100G connection.
2. change the default connection acceptance bandwidth of your device(i.e x90 here).